# IOS SDK - how to screen shot content of tableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How to screen-shot ALL content of tableView? (all content = visible are + NOT visible area)

I tried this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tableView.bounds.size);
[self.tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage* image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.imageView.image = image1;
```

but it doesn't work, I mean it's screenshot only visible area  :(

---

I solved it :))

here is the code :)

```
+ (UIImage *)captureView:(UIScrollView *)view inContentRect:(CGRect)rect{
    UIImage* image = nil;

    CGPoint savedContentOffset = view.contentOffset;
    CGRect savedFrame = view.frame;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.contentSize, 1, 0);
    view.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.contentSize.width, view.contentSize.height);

    [view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    view.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    view.frame = savedFrame;

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // after all of this, crop image to needed size
    return [Utils cropImage:image toRect:rect];                                 
}
```

Comment: You need to get the size of the enclosing scroll view, so perhaps use: `[(UIScrollView *)super contenSize]` instead of `self.tableView.bounds.size`?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. UITableView reuses the cells, which means, that the currently visible cells, are the only cells currently added to the UITableView. When you are scrolling a UITableView - let's say downwards - the UITableView takes out the disappearing cells at the top, reconfigures them for the new content to be available at the bottom, and then adds them there. Therefore if you were able to take a screenshot of the entire UITableView, you would see, that it would only have content in the currently visible area of the UITableView, as the non-displayed cells simply not exist.

Comment: @Trenskow Actually that's not as impossible as you have stated. Just some a little bit more logic, and you can do this :)

Comment: @FahriAzimov You are right. You could configure the cells manually, render it to an image an then composite it onto the final screenshot. That's how I would do it.

Comment: If you have solved the problem, would you mind editing your question so that your solution is instead an answer to your own question?

Comment: how would a table know it's content size without rendering the cells? it's not possible unless all cells are rendered and without dequeueing any of them. also, the content size of a table with cells that resize by it's content is not known to the table until they are created. it does work if the cells estimated size is equal to the final size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
+ (UIImage *)captureView:(UIScrollView *)view inContentRect:(CGRect)rect{
    UIImage* image = nil;

    CGPoint savedContentOffset = view.contentOffset;
    CGRect savedFrame = view.frame;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.contentSize, 1, 0);
    view.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.contentSize.width, view.contentSize.height);

    [view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    view.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    view.frame = savedFrame;

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // after all of this, crop image to needed size
    return [Utils cropImage:image toRect:rect];                                 
}
```

Comment: Any tips to get the selected segment of a uisegmentedcointrol to appear correctly? Right now, the selected segmnent has no text in it.

Comment: Can you tell me what are you passing for CGRect attribute in method? In my case I am passing tableview frame. But it is not showing the whole content of tableview..

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `contentSize.height` for getting the height of tableview

Try this

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.tableView.contentSize.height);
[self.tableView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage* image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.imageView.image = image1;
```

Comment: this will also makes a screen of only visible area of table view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. I can't provide the working code for what you want, I can just guide you how to do this. In the loop you have to get renders of all parts of the table by changing it's `contentOffset` and place each image in the array. After you got all the portions of the table view, you have to connect the parts of the table in to one image (draw each image in cgimagecontext, remember to set correct size for the result image). That's it, it's not that hard :) Hope this helps, Good luck!