# Transparent 20px at bottom on converting UITableView To UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimage

For converting TablevIew to UIImage, First I convert UITablevIew to UIImage by Following Code:

```
CGRect frame = aView.frame;
frame.size.height = aView.contentSize.height;
aView.frame = frame;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(aView.bounds.size);
[aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *saveImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then Save It into Document Directory By the following code

```
 NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(saveImage);

    NSFileManager *fileMan = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",aFilename];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [fileMan createFileAtPath:pdfFileName contents:imageData attributes:nil];
```

On opening the .png file from document directory, I found the image is 20px transparent from bottom.

[image: Bottom of Image is some how transparent]

Please share your ideas.. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: aView - it's a UITableView?

Comment: Yes. It isa tableview

Comment: check this solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18590620/ios-sdk-how-to-screen-shot-content-of-tableview

Comment: Now top is goes down to 20Px :(

Comment: If you followed the solution that @Igor points to, and don't get that to work, then edit the question to show what you have done exactly.

Answer (score -1):

20 px sounds like the status bar. Check the height of the bounds and maybe the y position of your frame.

Comment: When create img, it is either 20Px top /20 Px bottom. Its not about status bar